# What properties do graphs avoiding large regular subgraphs have?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $r$ and real $\delta \in (0,1)$.

Let $G$ be an undirected graph on $n$ vertices. Suppose that $G$ does **not** contain an $r$-regular subgraph on at least $\delta n$ vertices (i.e., $G$ does not have any "large regular subgraph"). What can we say about $G$?

**Question:** What properties must such a graph $G$ have?

For example, must $G$ be sparse (can we get good upper bounds on the total number of edges in $G$)? Are there interesting structural properties $G$ must have? I would be interested in hearing about results in this vein even for some concrete small values of $r$, and fixed choices of $\delta$.

Comment: Do you mean to ask about subgraphs here and not induced subgraphs?

Comment: Yes this question is about subgraphs (any subset of edges), definitely NOT induced subgraphs.

Comment: Have you seen this paper? https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/regular-subgraphs-of-graphs.pdf

May be useful. 

More relevant perhaps Pyber, Rodl, Szemeredi https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81119371.pdf
where they prove there are graphs with cnloglogn edges and no r-reg subgraph

Comment: I have not, thanks for the references! It seems like these papers show that already avoiding an $r$-regular subgraph on $n$ nodes implies the graph is quite sparse. I would interested in seeing if the even stronger condition (suggested from my post) of avoiding an $r$-regular subgraph even on any subset of at least $n/3$ nodes (for example) implies some stronger results.

Comment: FYI, the results above are not about spanning subgraphs

Comment: Oh, are those results for the existence of any (possibly very small) k-regular subgraph?